# Why is my iOS not detecting Bluetooth device names?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I am trying to list of bluetooth devices from my app.

My Bluetooth is enabled in settings but doesn't detect device names.

[image]

Comment: iOS version? And jailbroken or not?

Comment: Restarted the phone already?

Comment: @Globalnomad version 6.0.1 and not jailbroken device

Comment: @patrix i restarted even though its not coming

Comment: Are you sure the other bluetooth-device is working correctly? Test with another device and see if that shows up.

Comment: i tested in 2 ios devices i am not getting any list but in non ios devices i am getting these devices if i ask for pair its showing alert to pair but is not connecting and no showing device name also

Comment: It won't connect on non-iOS-devices?

Comment: not connecting to non-ios-devices and not showing ios devices

Comment: What device do you want to pair? Not all devices are supported.

Comment: even it not showing ios devices also

Answer (score 1):

The BT device that you are looking for has to be in *discovery mode*, or set to always *discoverable* in order to be visible to such device searches.

Comment: see in screenshots both are showing now discoverable

Comment: @ganeshmanoj Borderline means the other Bluetooth devices must be in discovery mode, not your iDevice. The `Now Discoverable` message applies to your iDevice.

Comment: @jaume ya others are also in discoverable mode only and those two screen shots are from two devices

Comment: @ganeshmanoj I see, that's not clear from your question, you should add more information to it: what device is your app running on? Or is it running in the simulator? Can those other two devices (the ones in the screenshots) be detected from, say, a computer?

Answer (score -1):

you can use apps like lightBlue or BLE scanner

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find the software and evaluate it themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.

Comment: Seconding @fsb. I'd personally recommend Find Blue as well.